# Question on Jupiter's Core

Tags: astrophysics, jupiter

A paper published by UC Berkley in 2010 (article about it here: https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2011/12/jupiter-eating-its-own-heart) tested what happens when magnesium oxide (one of the constituents of Jupiter's core) was put under the 40 million atmospheres and 16,000K temperatures.  The theoretical testing by Wilson and Militzer found that the magnesium oxide would dissolve as would the ice found at the core; and that the core would shrink because of this.....

I have a couple of questions about this...

1. Why wouldn't the MgO simply formed a stable crystal structure and stayed solid under that much pressure?
2. Is the pressure the reason for ice found at the core?
3. Is there any way to test the convection at the core boundary to determine how much of the core is left?